# Eclipse giving ambigous function warning on overloaded function

Tags: c++, eclipse, warnings

I have these two functions

```
bool checkIfPlayerWon(const F &field){
  return checkIfPlayerWon(field, player);
}

bool checkIfPlayerWon(const F &field, int current_player){
```

player is a member var of my class.

Now in my main I call

```
if(human_player.help.checkIfPlayerWon(my_field))
```

and

```
if(pc_player.help.checkIfPlayerWon(my_field))
```

Now everything compiles fine and the program works as intended. But eclipse gives me warnings, that the function `checkIfPlayerWon` is ambigous and then shows me:

```
'checkIfPlayerWon' is ambiguous '
Candidates are:
bool checkIfPlayerWon(const playfield &)
bool checkIfPlayerWon(const playfield &, int)
'
```

Why does eclipse do this? It's clear that it should call the first function, because it only has one argument. The gcc compiler gets it but why not eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse's C++ parser (part of CTD) is ok but not brilliant.  Trust your compiler. I usually end up turning it off.

Comment: I find it quite usefull though and would like it to work. Maybe somebody else knows if this is a bug or how to fix it.

Comment: I don't know if you have the same problem but I noticed that eclipse reports a bunch of errors like "ambiguous symbol" or invalid argument when I have vertical split of my code pane. I closed the split and, cleaned the project and the errors disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make Eclipse figure out which overloaded function you want, but the ambiguous warning is decently easy to turn off without disabling the entire C++ parser.

Go to Window->Preferences->C/C++->Cody Analysis and write ambiguous in the search tab. Then it will let you toggle the warning off.